# Run a script when the element is in view

Tags: javascript, scroll

Can someone fix this script so it runs when the element is in the view. In other words, it needs to wait until it's visible to run. Thanks! -Dan

```
$('.amount-chart').each(function(){
var $chart = $(this),
  size = parseFloat( $chart.outerWidth() ),
  clearSet;

$chart.css({
  height: size
})
.easyPieChart({
    size: size,
    animate: 2000,
            onStep: function(from, to, currentValue) {
                $(this.el).find('span.amount-counter').text(Math.round(currentValue));
            }
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){

   size = parseFloat( $chart.outerWidth() );

   $chart.css({
      height: size
   });

   //clearTimeout(clearSet);
   //clearSet = setTimeout(function(){
      $chart.removeData('easyPieChart').find('canvas').remove();
      $chart.easyPieChart({
         size: size,
         animate: 1
      });
   //}, 100);
});
```

});

Comment: Put it to playcode.io. Where your element not visible?

Comment: Hi Alex, I got the playcode.io to work ... http://true.playcode.io ... http://playcode.io/true

Comment: My answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for full description!
Look at [demo](http://playcode.io/75?tabs=script.js&output)

**HTML**

```
<div id="el">Pie Chart</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var inited = false
function init() {
   // init your chart
   // code here run once on element with id="el" will in viewport
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ( inited ) {
    return
  }

  if ( el.offsetTop >= window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop ) {
    inited = true
    init()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. You are the MAN!

Comment: this doesn't work, because this code runs the animation when scrolled, independently if the div is in viewport or not...